# iOS download and play mp3 file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayer, avaudioplayer

I am looking for the way how can I download and play mp3 file simultaneously.

I can download it, save to local storage and play after.

But, how can I start downloading and playing it simultaneously, and after it will completely download - save it to local storage. Which tools should I use for it?

Currently I use TCBlobDownload to download, after it I save it and AVAudioPlay to play.

Comment: post some code you used so far to accomplish the task - and for the saving file post a separate question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AVAssetResourceLoader` to plays an audio file as soon as there is enough data while continuing to download.

Configure the delegate of `resourceloader`

```
var playerAsset: AVAsset!

if fileURL.pathExtension.count == 0 {
    var components = URLComponents(url: fileURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!

    components.scheme = "fake" // make custom URL scheme
    components.path += ".mp3"

    playerAsset = AVURLAsset(url: components.url!)
    (playerAsset as! AVURLAsset).resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global())
} else {
    playerAsset = AVAsset(url: fileURL)
}

let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: playerAsset)
```

then, read audio's data and responds to the resource loader

```
// MARK: - AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    if let url = loadingRequest.request.url {
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        components.scheme = NSURLFileScheme // replace with the real URL scheme
        components.path = String(components.path.dropLast(4))

        if let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: components.url!.path),
            let fileSize = attributes[FileAttributeKey.size] as? Int64 {
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = "audio/mpeg3"
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = fileSize

            let requestedOffset = loadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedOffset
            let requestedLength = loadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength

            if let handle = try? FileHandle(forReadingFrom: components.url!) {
                handle.seek(toFileOffset: UInt64(requestedOffset))
                let data = handle.readData(ofLength: requestedLength)

                loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
                loadingRequest.finishLoading()

                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

And if you want to do this with objective c, refer [this](https://github.com/harshakuruwita/AVAssetResourceLoader)